# Angular: Show/hide selected rows with click event

Tags: angular

I have a table in which I'm showing some data for each selected row like this

```
<table>
    <th>Col-1</th>
    <th>Col-2</th>
    <th></th>
    <tr *ngFor="let obj of data; let i=index">
    <td>{{obj.id}}</td>
    <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
    <button (click)="myFunction(i)">Click</button>
    <br>
    <div>Some dynamic data</div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to display the div tag content for only clicked row and if I click other row button, that row with div should get displayed and previous div should be hidden. How do I achieve this? Please suggest

Comment: you can use a `showRow` boolean property to each row to toggle between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

In your component, declare a variable

```
visibleRrowIndex: number = null;
```

In your html

```
<button (click)="visibleRowIndex=i">Click</button>
    <br>
    <div [hidden]="visibleRowIndex !==i">Some dynamic data</div>
```

Comment: What do you call toggle effect? Like an animation? OP just wants to show/hide rows. Otherwise, he could use classes instead of `hidden`, and set CSS transitions on the classes

Comment: this is expected answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want that a "click" on the same, toggle, change the (click).

```
<button (click)="visibleRowIndex!==i?visibleRowIndex=i:null">Click</button>
```

Comment: one small typo i reckon

`visibleRowIndex !==i ? visibleRowIndex = i : visibleRowIndex = null`

Comment: ::glups:: @thoniv, thanks, but should be `visibleRowIndex=visibleRowIndex!==i?visibleRowIndex=i:-1`, the ternay operator is: `variable=(condition)?value if true:value if false` -I know that work your code but we should use the ternary operator to equal a variable-. NOTE: I prefer use -1 when nothing is selected